# Django How to UPDATE ... RETURNING

Tags: django, django-4.0

In Postgresql you can issue an UPDATE with a RETURNING statement in order to fetch some columns after you perform an update. This is useful because you can do this in one trip to the database instead of two.

```
UPDATE foo
SET bar = 10
WHERE id = 1
RETURNING baz
```

How can I simulate this in Django **without using a raw query** ?

I have seen some older questions on stackoverflow from a few years ago indicating this was not possible. Has anything changed in recent years?

I do not want to do the following, which requires two trips to the database:

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
foo.bar = 10
foo.save()
print(foo.baz)
```

I did see this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28682) from four years ago which was rejected. Has anything changed?